# One-to-one in EF only producing one Foreign Key

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I'm attempting to build a 1-1 relationship - a Tenant has a Url, and vice versa:

**Models**

```
public class Tenant {

    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int TenantId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Url Url { get; set; }
    public int UrlId { get; set; }

}

public class Url {

    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int UrlId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Tenant Tenant { get; set; }
    public int TenantId { get; set; }
}
```

**Configs**

```
public class UrlConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Url> {
    public UrlConfiguration() {

        HasKey(s => s.UrlId);

    }
}
public class TenantConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Tenant>
{
    public TenantConfiguration() {
        HasRequired(s => s.Url).WithRequiredPrincipal(s => s.Tenant);
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

I'd expect there to be a foreign key on both models... why is this not the case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A one-to-one relationship with both ends having required foreign keys cannot exist in a relational database. If saving a new Tenant record requires a URL record, but in order to create that URL record, that URL requires a Tenant record, where will you begin?

Even though on a database level it can't practically exist, this model will still work. From my experience, Entity Framework will enforce the dependency on application level, and will throw an EntityException when it detects that one of the entities you're trying to save has no relationship to one of the other.
It creates this database model so that it can still save your entities, and enforce relationships on an application level.

No, this isn't nice on a database level as the one-to-one constraint won't be enforced there. If you need the database constraints as well, consider merging the tables or redesigning your data structures so that a one-to-one relationship isn't necessary.

Comment: That's not quite true, in SQL Server, for example, you are able to [drop your constraints](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp) so you can effectively have a 1-1 relationship in both ends.

Comment: Dropping all constraints certainly won't lead to a one to one constraint, Bruno...

Comment: I meant drop them temporarly... Just for the sake of being able to add one of those tuples first.

Comment: what came first the tenant or the url?

Comment: I think you can do a true 1:1 relationship with EF using TPH. If you store both entities in the same table and enforce not null on at least one column from each entity within the database you will be forced to submit both entities at once? In any case 1:1 doesnt really make any sense in terms of a model. Instead you should use 0:1 or a single entity.